# Find a difference between two DataFrames with the same shape

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to find a difference between two excel files with the number of rows. I first want to sort both workbooks on two column then output a third file with the differences. I'm having trouble exporting a difference file properly.

Any help is highly appreciated!!! Thanks in advance!

import pandas as pd

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
  'ID' : ['3', '3', '55','55', '66', '66'],
 'date' : [20180102, 20180103, 20180104, 20180105, 20180106, 20180107],
   'age': [0, 1, 9, 4, 2, 3],
})



df2 = pd.DataFrame({
  'ID' : ['3', '55', '3','66', '55', '66'],
 'date' : [20180103, 20180104, 20180102, 20180106, 20180105, 20180107],
   'age': [0, 1, 9, 9, 8, 7],
})



df3 = df1.sort_values(by= ['ID', 'date'] , ascending=False)
df4 = df2.sort_values(by= ['ID', 'date'] , ascending=False)


dfDiff = df3.copy()

for row in range(dfDiff.shape[0]):
    for col in range(dfDiff.shape[1]):
        value_old = df3.iloc[row,col]
        value_new = df4.iloc[row,col]
        if value_old == value_new:
           dfDiff.iloc[row,col] = df4.iloc[row,col]
        else:
            dfDiff.iloc[row,col] = ('{}->{}').format(value_old,value_new)




writer = pd.ExcelWriter('diff', engine='xlsxwriter')

dfDiff.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='DIFF', index= False)

workbook = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['DIFF']
worksheet.hide_gridlines(2)


writer.save()
```

Comment: I think this question will be easier to answer if you can rephrase it to ask about comparing DataFrames. What is the "trouble"? Is there an error?

Comment: @AndyHayden I don't get an error message but the output file doesn't export as an excel file, it's an unreadable file.

Comment: Can you supply some sample data?

Comment: So `dfDiff` looks correct?

Comment: @IanThompson just added the sample data. The ID's and date will be the same for both workbooks but ordered in different rows and I'm trying to find the difference in the other columns after sorting them by ID and date.

Comment: @john anyway you can post it as code-formatted text instead of an image so we can copy it directly?

Comment: @john please use output of df.to_dict() or print(df.to_string()) insead of a screenshot. That way we can copy and paste it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are only missing the `.xlsx` at the end of your file path

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
  'ID' : ['3', '3', '55','55', '66', '66'],
 'date' : [20180102, 20180103, 20180104, 20180105, 20180106, 20180107],
   'age': [0, 1, 9, 4, 2, 3],
})



df2 = pd.DataFrame({
  'ID' : ['3', '55', '3','66', '55', '66'],
 'date' : [20180103, 20180104, 20180102, 20180106, 20180105, 20180107],
   'age': [0, 1, 9, 9, 8, 7],
})



df3 = df1.sort_values(by= ['ID', 'date'] , ascending=False)
df4 = df2.sort_values(by= ['ID', 'date'] , ascending=False)


dfDiff = df3.copy()

for row in range(dfDiff.shape[0]):
    for col in range(dfDiff.shape[1]):
        value_old = df3.iloc[row,col]
        value_new = df4.iloc[row,col]
        if value_old == value_new:
            dfDiff.iloc[row,col] = df4.iloc[row,col]
        else:
            dfDiff.iloc[row,col] = ('{}->{}').format(value_old,value_new)



# added `.xlsx' to path here
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('diff.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

dfDiff.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='DIFF', index= False)

workbook = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['DIFF']
worksheet.hide_gridlines(2)


writer.save()
```